# Game theory book and problem book recommendation.

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, book-recommendation

I want one or few books on game theory that contain most of the game theory that there is and also problem book that hopefully will have all types of problems up to olympiad level questions. please if somebody knows something that could help, please share it. thank you

PS. These are necessary for an olympiad on game theory that will be held in two weeks.

Answer (score 3):

For Game Theory, I suggest *Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays*, by Elwyn R. Berlekamp, John H. Conway, and Richard K. Guy.

For problems, I suggest *The IMO Compendium: A Collection of Problems Suggested for The International Mathematical Olympiads: 1959-2009*, by D. Djukić, V. Janković, I. Matić, and Petrović, N.